# delete django formset with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, formset

hi I have improved add Django formset and save the extra form data now I want to delete the extra forms if the user need to delete some of them how to do that

this is my template and javascript code for add extra forms and its work totally fine

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <form  method="post" id="regForm" action=".">
        {% csrf_token %}
  <h1>Visa Info:</h1>
  <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div class="tab">Name:
    {{form.visa_type|as_crispy_field}}

              {{ form.arrival_time|as_crispy_field }}

              {{ form.departure_time|as_crispy_field }}

            {{form.number_of_vistor|as_crispy_field}}
            {{form.purpose_trip|as_crispy_field}}
            {{form.city|as_crispy_field}}
            <h1>user info</h1>
            <div id="userform">
            {% for form_data in formset %}
            {{ form_data.management_form }}
            {{form_data.first_name|as_crispy_field}}
            {{form_data.last_name|as_crispy_field}}
            {{form_data.middle_name|as_crispy_field}}

              {{form_data.date_of_birth|as_crispy_field}}



            {{form_data.gender|as_crispy_field}}
            {{form_data.passport|as_crispy_field}}

              {{form_data.passport_ex|as_crispy_field}}


            {{form_data.nationality|as_crispy_field}}

            {% endfor %}

            </div>
            <a class="btn btn-default" id="{{ formset.prefix }}">add</a>
            {{ formset.management_form }}
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Dliver Information:
    {{emailForm.email|as_crispy_field}}
    {{emailForm.instructions|as_crispy_field}}
    Do you want the real visa to be dlever to you?
    <div class="btn btn-primary" id="show">yes</div>
    <div class="btn btn-danger" id="hide">no</div>
    <div class="menu">
        {{dliveryform|crispy}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
{% block javascript %}
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        // $('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker();
        var input = $('#userform').find('input')
        // console.log(input)
        // $("body").on('click', '.add-form-row',function () {
        //  return addForm($(this), String($(this).attr('id')));
        // });
        // var a = 1;
        // while (a) {
        //  console.log('test')
        // }
        $('#id_number_of_vistor').change(()=>{
            var key = $('#id_number_of_vistor option:selected').text();
            console.log(key)
            if (key > 1){
                for ( ;key > 1; --key) {
                    cloneMore('#userform','Visitor');
                }
            }else{
                //delete the formset
            }

        })
        // console.log($('#id_number_of_vistor option:selected').text())
        $('.menu').hide("slide");
        $('#show').click(function() {
          $('.menu').toggle("slide");
        });
        $('#hide').click(function() {
          $('.menu').hide("slide");
        });
    });


    function cloneMore(selector, type) {
        var newElement = $(selector).clone(true);
        var total = $('#id_' + type + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
        newElement.find(':input').each(function() {
            var name = $(this).attr('name').replace('-' + (total-1) + '-','-' + total + '-');
            var id = 'id_' + name;
            $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id}).val('').removeAttr('checked');
        });
        newElement.find('label').each(function() {
            var newFor = $(this).attr('for').replace('-' + (total-1) + '-','-' + total + '-');
            $(this).attr('for', newFor);
        });
        total++;
        $('#id_' + type + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total);

        $(selector).after(newElement);
    }


    </script>
{% endblock javascript %}
```

i want to delete it with javascript how to do that?

i have try many things with javascript but its not working

Comment: You should try https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset.

Comment: if i use it i have to rewrite all of my code

Comment: You can still take some pointers on how to delete. basically you need to find the form which needs to be deleted, then remove that form and iterate over the all the remaining forms to update their `name` attribute.